# Maximum array sum with limit

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-programming

Cant find this question.We are given an array,we have to find maximum sum of consecutive elements but the maximum sum limit is given.For ex- in array 7 3 5 6,and maximum allowed sum is 9,so the answer should be 8 is given.The only thing i find on internet is maximum possible sum,but i want to find the limited sum

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{
    int n,m,a[100],dp[100];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n&&sum<=m;i++) 
    {
        int j=0;
        sum=sum+a[i];
        if(sum>m)
        {
            dp[j]=sum-a[i];
        }
        else dp[j]=sum;
        j++;
        sum=0;
    }
    sort(dp,dp+n);
    cout<<dp[n-2];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i can't think of an algorithm.
c++ preferred.

Comment: tried to come up with some sort of this algo
/*#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int n,m,a[100],dp[100];
 cin>>n;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  cin>>a[i];
 }
 int sum=0;
 for(int i=0;i<n&&sum<=m;i++)
 {
  int j=0;
  sum=sum+a[i];
  if(sum>m)
  {
  dp[j]=sum-a[i];
     }
     else
     dp[j]=sum;
     j++;
  sum=0;
 }
 sort(dp,dp+n);
 cout<<dp[n-2];
 return 0;
}*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers in the array are all positive numbers, here is an O(n) algorithm: Use 2 pointers, one pointing to the start position and another pointing to the end position. Move the later pointer ahead, whenever the current sum is larger than the limit, move the first pointer and minus the sum.

Simple code:

```
int sum=0,ans=0,p1=0,p2=0;
while (p2<n) {
    sum+=num[p2];
    p2++;
    while (sum>limit && p1<p2) {
        sum-=num[p1];
        p1++;
    }
    ans=max(ans,sum);
}
while (p1<n) {
    sum-=num[p1];
    p1++;
    if (sum<=limit) ans=max(ans,sum);
}
return ans;
```

If the array contains negative numbers, currently I can only think of an O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can find full answer to your question here:
[Algorithm for Filling bag maximally (this is not the knapsack 0/1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721107/algorithm-for-filling-bag-maximally-this-is-not-the-knapsack-0-1)
This question was created by me, feel free to ask for details :)